# Notation for the relationship $a > b, \forall a \in A, \forall b \in B$ for the sets $A, B$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I encountered the relationship

$$
a > b, \forall a \in A, \forall b \in B
$$

Is there any notation for the relationship between the sets $A$ and $B$? Can I say $A > B$?

Comment: Depending on the nature of your sets and the order on their elements, you _might_ be able to abbreviate your claim to $\min A > \max B$, for example if they are finite sets of numbers.

Comment: You could search for strong set ordering and set order. Those concepts are similar to yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define
$$ A>B\ :\Leftrightarrow\  \forall a\in A,\forall b\in B, a>b$$
and beginning with the line after that definitioin you can use it.